# HTML Canvas & JavaScript - Scale Object on Hover

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas

The script below draws 4 curved rectangles and detects if they are hovered over or clicked on with `mouseup` and `mousemove` event listeners. When one of the rectangles is hovered over, I would like it to grow slightly over the course of a second - it should then shrink back when the cursor moves off the rectangle.

The problem I have is that the only way I can think of doing this is by writing a function inside the `if (this.selected) {` clause which plots a new version of the rectangle for each frame in an animation lasting a second, but this clause is inside the function that plots a new version of the rectangle itself! How, then, can I write a function outside of `curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect` which only runs when the cursor is over one of the rectangles? Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  canvasX=c.offsetLeft,
  canvasY=c.offsetTop,
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

var curvedRect = function(id, x, y, w, h) {
 this.id = id;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 this.selected = false;
}

curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect = function() {
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth='8';
 ctx.strokeStyle='white';
 ctx.moveTo(this.x+10, this.y);
 ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.w-10, this.y);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x+this.w, this.y, this.x+this.w, this.y+10);
 ctx.lineTo(this.x+this.w, this.y+this.h-10);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x+this.w, this.y+this.h, this.x+this.w-10, this.y+this.h);
 ctx.lineTo(this.x+10, this.y+this.h);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x, this.y+this.h, this.x, this.y+this.h-10);
 ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y+10);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(this.x, this.y, this.x+10, this.y);
 ctx.stroke();
 if (this.selected) {
        // BM67 edit By Blindman67 removed annoying alert and replaced it with console.log 
        // As I did not want to add elsewhere to the code to declare hoverMessageShown is safely declared here to stop the console repeating the message.
        if(window["hoverMessageShown"] === undefined){
           window["hoverMessageShown"] = true; 
       console.log('When hovered over, I would like this box to grow slightly over a short period of time (say a second). When the mouse is removed I would like it to shrink back.')
        }
        // BM67 end.
 }
}

curvedRect.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= this.x) && (x <= (this.w+this.x)) && (y >= this.y) && (y <= (this.h+this.y));
}

var Paint = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
 this.shapes = [];
}

Paint.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
 this.shapes.push(shape);
}

Paint.prototype.render = function() {
 this.element.w = this.element.w;
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].makeCurvedRect();
 }
}

Paint.prototype.setSelected = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].selected = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.select = function(x, y) {
 for (var i=this.shapes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (this.shapes[i].hitTest(x, y)) {
   return this.shapes[i];
  }
 }
 return null
}

var paint = new Paint(c);
var img1 = new curvedRect('1', 200, 55, 150, 150);
var img2 = new curvedRect('2', 375, 55, 150, 150);
var img3 = new curvedRect('3', 200, 230, 150, 150);
var img4 = new curvedRect('4', 375, 230, 150, 150);

paint.addShape(img1);
paint.addShape(img2);
paint.addShape(img3);
paint.addShape(img4);

paint.render();

function mouseUp(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (shape) {
  alert(shape.id);
 }
 // console.log('selected shape: ', shape);
}

function mouseMove(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setSelected(shape);
}

c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='game.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "750" height = "500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited you code to change the alert to console out put. I think most people prefer the alert not to pop up when you just move the mouse over without intention to interact. Personally I don't see the need for the message as you have already explained in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the makeCurvedRect method to something like this:

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
  canvasX=c.offsetLeft,
  canvasY=c.offsetTop,
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

var curvedRect = function(id, x, y, w, h) {
 this.id = id;
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 this.selected = false;
}

curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect = function() { 
    var delta = this.selected?10:0 ;
    var x = this.x - delta;
    var y = this.y - delta;
    var w  = this.w + (2*delta);
    var h = this.h + (2*delta);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth='8';
 ctx.strokeStyle='white';
 ctx.moveTo(x+10, y);
 ctx.lineTo(x+ w -10, y);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + w,  y,x + w,y + 10);
 ctx.lineTo( x + w,  y + h-10);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x + w, y + h,  x +  w - 10,  y + h);
 ctx.lineTo(x + 10,y + h);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo( x,  y + h, x,  y+h-10);
 ctx.lineTo(x, y+10);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+10, y);
 ctx.stroke();
  
}

curvedRect.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= this.x) && (x <= (this.w+this.x)) && (y >= this.y) && (y <= (this.h+this.y));
}

var Paint = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
 this.shapes = [];
}

Paint.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
 this.shapes.push(shape);
}

Paint.prototype.render = function() {
 this.element.width = this.element.width;
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].makeCurvedRect();
 }
}

Paint.prototype.setSelected = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].selected = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.select = function(x, y) {
 for (var i=this.shapes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (this.shapes[i].hitTest(x, y)) {
   return this.shapes[i];
  }
 }
 return null
}

var paint = new Paint(c);
var img1 = new curvedRect('1', 200, 55, 150, 150);
var img2 = new curvedRect('2', 375, 55, 150, 150);
var img3 = new curvedRect('3', 200, 230, 150, 150);
var img4 = new curvedRect('4', 375, 230, 150, 150);

paint.addShape(img1);
paint.addShape(img2);
paint.addShape(img3);
paint.addShape(img4);

paint.render();

function mouseUp(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (shape) {
  alert(shape.id);
 }
 // console.log('selected shape: ', shape);
}

function mouseMove(event) {
 var x = event.x - canvasX;
 var y = event.y - canvasY;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setSelected(shape);
}

c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

```css
canvas {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #FF9900;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='game.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="game" width = "750" height = "500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks again for this answer. I'm not sure if you're still active but I'm stuck on a related problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45062247/html-canvas-javascript-selection-menu-setting-initial-and-sustaining-curre.