# HTML Canvas & JavaScript - Selection Menu - Setting Initial and Sustaining Current Selection

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas

In the HTML canvas below I have a selection menu which triggers the drawing of an image beside it dependent on what is selected (numbers 1-5 in the example below). The JavaScript uses the pseudo-object approach to storing/manipulating images drawn on the canvas. Besides the `EventListener`'s attached to the canvas, there is one `EventListener` attached to the whole window which resizes the canvas within a strict aspect ratio when the window size is changed.

The problem I am currently having with this is that the selection is cleared when the EventListener is triggered (when the window size is changed). To replicate this in the example below, you will have to run the code snippet in full screen mode and change your browser window's size. Instead, I would like the the current selection to be maintained after the window (and correspondingly, the canvas') size change. I have tried assigning the current selection to a variable, but I could only get it to leave a static selection where the onHover animation does not work.

Also, related to this, I am trying to set an initial selection that is selected on the first canvas draw until one of the other options is selected. In this case, when the script initially loads, I would like the number 1 and its corresponding image to be automatically selected/displayed until a new selection is made. Again, assigning this as an `initialSelection` variable or calling `makeCurvedRect` independently leaves a static selection, by which I mean the `curvedRect` (image) is not animated `onHover`.

I'm very unsure how to achieve either of these results so any help will be much appreciated. Apologies for the large amount of code but I could not manage to condense it any more than this.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
    rect = c.getBoundingClientRect(),
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

c.width  = window.innerWidth;
c.height = (2/3)*c.width;

numberImages = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZIUz.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/6beTF.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZk2H.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K743.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMMmQ.png'];

var curvedRect = function(number, x, y, w, h) {
    this.text = number.toString();
 this.img = new Image();
 this.img.src=numberImages[number-1];
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 this.hovered = false;
 this.clicked = false;
 this.visible = false;
}

var selected;
curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect = function() {
 var delta=0, theta=0;
 if (this.hovered) {
  delta = (c.height*(3/500));
  theta = -0.01;
  shadowColor = '#000000';
  shadowBlur = 20;
  shadowOffsetX = 5;
  shadowOffsetY = 5;
 } else {
  delta = 0;
  theta = 0;
  shadowColor = '#9F3A9B';
  shadowBlur = 0;
  shadowOffsetX = 0;
  shadowOffsetY = 0;
 }
 var x = this.x-delta;
 var y = this.y-delta;
 var w = this.w+(2*delta);
 var h = this.h+(2*delta);
 var cornerRounder = (c.height*(10/500))
 ctx.rotate(theta);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth='12';
 ctx.strokeStyle='white';
 ctx.moveTo(x+cornerRounder, y);
 ctx.lineTo(x+w-cornerRounder, y);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+cornerRounder);
 ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-cornerRounder);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-cornerRounder, y+h);
 ctx.lineTo(x+cornerRounder, y+h);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h-cornerRounder);
 ctx.lineTo(x, y+cornerRounder);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+cornerRounder, y);
 ctx.shadowColor = shadowColor;
 ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
 ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
 ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
 ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
 ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
 ctx.drawImage(this.img, x+(c.width*(2.5/750)), y+(c.height*(2.5/500)), w-cornerRounder/2, h-cornerRounder/2);
 ctx.rotate(-theta);
}

curvedRect.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= this.x) && (x <= (this.w+this.x)) && (y >= this.y) && (y <= (this.h+this.y));
}

var selectionForMenu = function(id, text, y) {
 this.id = id;
 this.text = text;
 this.y = y;
 this.hovered = false;
 this.clicked = false;
 this.lastClicked = false;
 this.visible = true;
}

function makeTextForSelected(text, y) {
 ctx.font='bold '+(c.height*(12/500))+'px Noto Sans'; // check
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.textAlign='center';
 ctx.fillText(text, (c.width*(200/750)), y);
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.makeSelection = function() {
 ctx.globalAlpha=0.75;
 var fillColor='#A84FA5';
 if (this.hovered) {
  if (this.clicked) {
   if (this.lastClicked) {
    fillColor='#E4C7E2';
    makeTextForSelected(this.text, c.height*(375/500));
   } else {
    fillColor='#D5A9D3';
   }
  } else if (this.lastClicked) {
   fillColor='#D3A4D0';
   makeTextForSelected(this.text, c.height*(375/500));
  } else {
   fillColor='#BA74B7';
  }
 } else if (this.lastClicked) {
  fillColor='#C78DC5';
  makeTextForSelected(this.text, c.height*(375/500));
 } else {
  fillColor='#A84FA5';
 }
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
 ctx.fillRect(c.width*(400/750), this.y, c.width*(350/750), c.height*(100/500))
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.font=c.height*(10/500)+'px Noto Sans';
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.textAlign='left';
 ctx.fillText(this.text, c.width*(410/750), this.y+(c.height*(38/500)));

 ctx.globalAlpha=1;
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= (c.width*(400/750)) && (x <= c.width) && (y >= this.y) &&
 (y <= (this.y+(c.height*(100/500))) && !((x >= c.width*(400/750) && (y > c.height*(450/500))))));
}

var Paint = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
 this.shapes = [];
}

Paint.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
 this.shapes.push(shape);
}

Paint.prototype.render = function() {

 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.element.width, this.element.height);

 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeSelection();
  }
  catch(err) {}
  try {
   if(this.shapes[i].lastClicked == true) {
    this.shapes[i].rect.makeCurvedRect();
   }
  }
  catch(err) {}
 }

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, (c.height*(25/500)));
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle='#BC77BA';
 ctx.fillRect(0, (c.height*(450/500)), c.width, (c.height*(50/500)));
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.font='bold '+(c.height*(10/500))+'px Noto Sans';
 ctx.fillStyle='#9F3A9B';
 ctx.textAlign='center';
 ctx.fillText('Test', (c.width*(365/750)), (c.height*(17/500)));
}

Paint.prototype.setHovered = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].hovered = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setClicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].clicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setUnclicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  if (shape.constructor.name==this.shapes[i].constructor.name) {
   this.shapes[i].clicked = false;
    if (shape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
    this.shapes[i].lastClicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
    if (this.shapes[i].lastClicked == true) {
     this.shapes[i].rect.visible = true;
    } else {
     this.shapes[i].rect.visible = false;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.select = function(x, y) {
 for (var i=this.shapes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (this.shapes[i].visible == true && this.shapes[i].hitTest(x, y)) {
   return this.shapes[i];
  }
 }
 return null
}

var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var paint = new Paint(c);
var selection = [];
for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
 selection.push(new selectionForMenu(i+1, numbers[i], c.height*(25/500)+(c.height*((i*100)/500))));
}
for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
 var img = new curvedRect(i+1, (c.width*(112.5/750)), (c.height*(100/500)), (c.height*(175/500)), (c.height*(175/500)));
 paint.addShape(img)
 selection[i].rect = img;
}

for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
 paint.addShape(selection[i])
}

paint.render();

var clickedShape, clickIndex=0;
function mouseDown(event) {
 var x = (event.pageX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*c.width;
 var y = (event.pageY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*c.height;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (shape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
  if (clickIndex==0) {
   clickedShape=shape;
   clickIndex=1;
  } else if (clickIndex==1) {
   clickIndex=0;
  }
 }
 paint.setClicked(shape);
}

function mouseUp(event) {
 var x = (event.pageX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*c.width;
 var y = (event.pageY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*c.height;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (clickedShape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
  if (x>c.width*(400/750) && y>c.height*(25/500) && y<c.height*(450/500)) {
   paint.setUnclicked(shape);
  } else if (shape && !(shape instanceof selectionForMenu)) {
   paint.setUnclicked(shape);
  }
 }
}

function mouseMove(event) {
 var x = (event.pageX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*c.width;
 var y = (event.pageY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*c.height;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setHovered(shape);
}

function paintCanvas() {
  c.width  = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = (2/3)*c.width;
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');
  rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();

  paint = new Paint(c);
  selection = [];
  for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    selection.push(new selectionForMenu(i+1, numbers[i], c.height*(25/500)+(c.height*((i*100)/500))));
  }
  for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    var img = new curvedRect(i+1, (c.width*(112.5/750)), (c.height*(100/500)), (c.height*(175/500)), (c.height*(175/500)));
    paint.addShape(img)
    selection[i].rect = img;
  }

  for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    paint.addShape(selection[i])
  }
  paint.render();
}

paintCanvas();

window.addEventListener('resize', paintCanvas);
c.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

```css
canvas {
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background: #9F3A9B;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='wordpractice.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='container'>
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
 </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='scaleStack.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must make the paint class (in your code) once,

```js
function Game (elementID,width,height){
 this.elementID = elementID;
 this.element   = document.getElementById(elementID);
 this.width = width;
 this.height = height;

 this.palette = {
  color1:'#fff',
  color2:'#000',
  color3:'#9F3A9B',
  color4:'#a84ea5',
  color5:'#b56ab2',
  color6:'#bf7dbd',
  color7:'#d5a8d2'
 }; 

 this.element.style.width = width + 'px';
 this.element.style.height= height + 'px';
 this.element.style.border='solid thin ' + this.palette.color2;
 this.element.style.display= 'block';
 //this.element.style.margin='1em auto';
 this.element.style.background=this.palette.color3;


 this.initialGame();
}

Game.prototype.initialGame = function(){
 this.canvas  = document.createElement("canvas");
 this.canvas.width  =  this.width;
 this.canvas.height =  this.height;
 this.element.appendChild(this.canvas);

 this.initialTitle();
 this.initialSideButtons();
 this.initialBoard();
 this.initialFooter();

    // initial selection
    this.sideButtons.select(this.sideButtons.buttons[0]);

 this.resize(this.width,this.height);
 this.render();
 this.attachEvents();
}

Game.prototype.attachEvents = function(){
 var element = this.element;
 
 var getX = function(evt){return evt.offsetX || evt.layerX || (evt.clientX - element.offsetLeft);};
 var getY = function(evt){return evt.offsetY || evt.layerY || (evt.clientY - element.offsetTop);};
 
 var game = this;
 this.element.addEventListener('mousemove',function(evt){
  game.hover(getX(evt),getY(evt));
  game.render();
 });

 this.element.addEventListener('click',function(evt){
  game.sideButtons.click();
  game.render();
 });
}

Game.prototype.onSelect = function(button){
 this.selected = button;
};

Game.prototype.hover=function(x,y){
 this.hoverX = x;
 this.hoverY = y;
};

Game.prototype.initialBoard = function(){
 var game = this;
 var Board = function(){
  this.left = 0;
  this.top  = 0;
  this.width =0;
  this.height=0;
 };

 Board.prototype.render = function(ctx){
  if(game.selected){

   var shapeWidth = this.width/3;

   ctx.fillStyle = game.palette.color1;
   ctx.strokeStyle = game.palette.color1;
   var fontSize =  14;
   ctx.font = 'bold '+ fontSize +'px Noto Sans';
   ctx.textAlign='center';
   ctx.lineWidth=8;
   ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
   ctx.strokeRect(this.left + this.width/2 - (shapeWidth/2),this.height/2-(shapeWidth/2) + this.top,shapeWidth,shapeWidth);
   ctx.fillText(game.selected.text,this.left + this.width/2,this.height/2 + this.top );
  }
 };

 this.board =  new Board();
};

Game.prototype.initialSideButtons = function(){
 var game = this;
 var ButtonBar =function(text){
  this.text = text;
  this.left = 0;
  this.top  = 0;
  this.width = 1;
  this.height= 1;
  this.selected=false;
 };

 ButtonBar.prototype.hitTest=function(x,y){
  return  (this.left < x) && (x < (this.left + this.width)) &&
    (this.top <y) && (y < (this.top + this.height));
 };

 ButtonBar.prototype.getColor=function(){
  var hovered = this.hitTest(game.hoverX,game.hoverY);
  
  if(this.selected){
   if(hovered)
   {
    return game.palette.color7;
   }
   return game.palette.color6;
  }
  
  if(hovered){
   return game.palette.color5;
  }
  return game.palette.color4;
 };

 ButtonBar.prototype.render = function(ctx){
  var fontSize = 14;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.getColor();
  ctx.fillRect(this.left,this.top,this.width,this.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = game.palette.color1;
  ctx.textAlign = 'left';
  ctx.font ='bold '+ fontSize +'px Noto Sans';
  ctx.fillText(this.text,this.left + 10,this.top+ this.height/2);
 };

 var SideButtons = function(){
  this.buttons = [];
  this.width = 1;
  this.height= 1;
  this.left=1;
  this.top=1;
 };

 SideButtons.prototype.render = function(ctx){
  if(!this.buttons.length){
   return;
  }

  var height = this.height / this.buttons.length ;
  for(var i=0;i<this.buttons.length;i++){
   var btn = this.buttons[i];
   btn.left = this.left;
   btn.top = i * height + this.top;
   btn.width = this.width;
   btn.height = height;
   this.buttons[i].render(ctx);
  }
 };

 SideButtons.prototype.click = function(){
            var current = null;
  for(var i=0;i<this.buttons.length;i++){
   var btn = this.buttons[i];
                    if(  btn.hitTest(game.hoverX,game.hoverY))
                     {
    this.select(btn);
                            break;
    }
  }
 };

    SideButtons.prototype.select = function(btn)
    {
       for(var i=0;i<this.buttons.length;i++)
       {
          this.buttons[i].selected = false;
       }
       btn.selected=true;
       game.onSelect(btn);
    };

 this.sideButtons = new SideButtons();

 var btn1 = new ButtonBar('Button 1');
 var btn2 = new ButtonBar('Button 2');
 var btn3 = new ButtonBar('Button 3');
 var btn4 = new ButtonBar('Button 4');

 this.sideButtons.buttons.push(btn1);
 this.sideButtons.buttons.push(btn2);
 this.sideButtons.buttons.push(btn3);
 this.sideButtons.buttons.push(btn4);

};

Game.prototype.initialTitle = function(){
 var Title = function(value,width,height){
  this.value=value;
  this.width = width;
  this.height= height;
 };

 var game = this;
 Title.prototype.render=function(ctx){
  var k = 2;
  var fontSize =  this.height / k;
  ctx.fillStyle=game.palette.color1;
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,this.width,this.height);
  ctx.font='bold '+ fontSize +'px Noto Sans'; // check
  ctx.fillStyle=game.palette.color3;
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.fillText(this.value,this.width/2,this.height - fontSize/2);

 };

 this.title = new Title('Test',this.width,this.height / 10);
}

Game.prototype.initialFooter = function(){
 var Footer = function(){
  this.width = 1;
  this.height= 1;
  this.left=0;
  this.top=0;
 }
 var game = this;
 Footer.prototype.render = function(ctx){
  ctx.fillStyle =  game.palette.color5;
  ctx.fillRect(this.left,this.top,this.width,this.height);
 };

 this.footer = new Footer();
};

Game.prototype.resetCanvas = function(){
 this.canvas.width  =  this.width;
 this.canvas.height =  this.height;
};

Game.prototype.render = function(){
 this.resetCanvas();

 var context = this.canvas.getContext('2d');

 this.title.render(context);
 this.sideButtons.render(context);
 this.board.render(context);
 this.footer.render(context);

};

Game.prototype.resize =  function (width,height){
 this.width = width;
 this.height= height;

 this.element.style.width = width + 'px';
 this.element.style.height= height+ 'px';
 
 this.title.height = this.height / 14;
 this.title.width   = this.width;

 this.footer.height = this.title.height;
 this.footer.width  = this.width;
 this.footer.top = this.height - this.footer.height;
 this.footer.left = 0;

 this.board.top   = this.title.height;
 this.board.left  = 0;
 this.board.width = this.width  - 250;//or -> this.width / 2
 this.board.height= this.height - this.title.height - this.footer.height;

 this.sideButtons.left= this.board.width;
 this.sideButtons.top = this.board.top;
 this.sideButtons.width = this.width - this.board.width;
 this.sideButtons.height = this.board.height;

 this.render();
};


var game = new Game('game',window.innerWidth -50,window.innerWidth * 2/3);

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
 game.resize(window.innerWidth -50,window.innerWidth * 2/3);
});
```

```html
 <div id='container'>
  <div id="game"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. The only thing I'm still not sure of is setting an initial selection when the `game` first loads.

Comment: And, related to that, not losing the highlighting of the current selection in the `SideButtons` when clicking on anything other than a new selection.

Comment: Sorry, one more thing - where should I put `window` `eventListener`'s to be compatible with the on-going `Game`? The reason I ask is that the full script uses `requestAnimationFrame` to emulate a scroll with a scroll-on-hover event on the `selectionMenu`, or as you called it, the `sideButtons`. There is also a language `select` that changes the language of the text in the `sideButtons` which, in its current state, also requires an `eventListener`. If this is not enough to go on I can update the other question regarding the css `select` with an example of what I mean as it is related.

Comment: It depends, I must see the whole code. @JonathanConnell

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your resize handler calls `paintCanvas` and in your `paintCanvas` method you are assigning your global `paint` variable to new an entirely new instance of `paint`. This entirely wipes out your state and forces the canvas to be redrawn to match the initial state of an initial page load. Instead, you need to maintain your state, clear your canvas and render it again with its existing state but just with new sizes.

```
function paintCanvas() {
    c.width  = window.innerWidth;
    c.height = (2/3)*c.width;
    ctx=c.getContext('2d');
    rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();

    //paint = new Paint(c);
```

Commenting out `//paint = new Paint(c);` leaves your state intact. You still some remnants you need to flush out and redraw since you are no longer destroying your state.

```js
var c=document.getElementById('game'),
    rect = c.getBoundingClientRect(),
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

c.width  = window.innerWidth;
c.height = (2/3)*c.width;

numberImages = ['https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZIUz.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/6beTF.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZk2H.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K743.png','https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMMmQ.png'];

var curvedRect = function(number, x, y, w, h) {
    this.text = number.toString();
 this.img = new Image();
 this.img.src=numberImages[number-1];
 this.x = x;
 this.y = y;
 this.w = w;
 this.h = h;
 this.hovered = false;
 this.clicked = false;
 this.visible = false;
}

var selected;
curvedRect.prototype.makeCurvedRect = function() {
 var delta=0, theta=0;
 if (this.hovered) {
  delta = (c.height*(3/500));
  theta = -0.01;
  shadowColor = '#000000';
  shadowBlur = 20;
  shadowOffsetX = 5;
  shadowOffsetY = 5;
 } else {
  delta = 0;
  theta = 0;
  shadowColor = '#9F3A9B';
  shadowBlur = 0;
  shadowOffsetX = 0;
  shadowOffsetY = 0;
 }
 var x = this.x-delta;
 var y = this.y-delta;
 var w = this.w+(2*delta);
 var h = this.h+(2*delta);
 var cornerRounder = (c.height*(10/500))
 ctx.rotate(theta);
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth='12';
 ctx.strokeStyle='white';
 ctx.moveTo(x+cornerRounder, y);
 ctx.lineTo(x+w-cornerRounder, y);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+cornerRounder);
 ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-cornerRounder);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-cornerRounder, y+h);
 ctx.lineTo(x+cornerRounder, y+h);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h-cornerRounder);
 ctx.lineTo(x, y+cornerRounder);
 ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+cornerRounder, y);
 ctx.shadowColor = shadowColor;
 ctx.shadowBlur = shadowBlur;
 ctx.shadowOffsetX = shadowOffsetX;
 ctx.shadowOffsetY = shadowOffsetY;
 ctx.stroke();
 ctx.shadowBlur = 0;
 ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
 ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
 ctx.drawImage(this.img, x+(c.width*(2.5/750)), y+(c.height*(2.5/500)), w-cornerRounder/2, h-cornerRounder/2);
 ctx.rotate(-theta);
}

curvedRect.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= this.x) && (x <= (this.w+this.x)) && (y >= this.y) && (y <= (this.h+this.y));
}

var selectionForMenu = function(id, text, y) {
 this.id = id;
 this.text = text;
 this.y = y;
 this.hovered = false;
 this.clicked = false;
 this.lastClicked = false;
 this.visible = true;
}

function makeTextForSelected(text, y) {
 ctx.font='bold '+(c.height*(12/500))+'px Noto Sans'; // check
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.textAlign='center';
 ctx.fillText(text, (c.width*(200/750)), y);
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.makeSelection = function() {
 ctx.globalAlpha=0.75;
 var fillColor='#A84FA5';
 if (this.hovered) {
  if (this.clicked) {
   if (this.lastClicked) {
    fillColor='#E4C7E2';
    makeTextForSelected(this.text, c.height*(375/500));
   } else {
    fillColor='#D5A9D3';
   }
  } else if (this.lastClicked) {
   fillColor='#D3A4D0';
   makeTextForSelected(this.text, c.height*(375/500));
  } else {
   fillColor='#BA74B7';
  }
 } else if (this.lastClicked) {
  fillColor='#C78DC5';
  makeTextForSelected(this.text, c.height*(375/500));
 } else {
  fillColor='#A84FA5';
 }
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle=fillColor;
 ctx.fillRect(c.width*(400/750), this.y, c.width*(350/750), c.height*(100/500))
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.font=c.height*(10/500)+'px Noto Sans';
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.textAlign='left';
 ctx.fillText(this.text, c.width*(410/750), this.y+(c.height*(38/500)));

 ctx.globalAlpha=1;
}

selectionForMenu.prototype.hitTest = function(x, y) {
 return (x >= (c.width*(400/750)) && (x <= c.width) && (y >= this.y) &&
 (y <= (this.y+(c.height*(100/500))) && !((x >= c.width*(400/750) && (y > c.height*(450/500))))));
}

var Paint = function(element) {
 this.element = element;
 this.shapes = [];
}

Paint.prototype.addShape = function(shape) {
 this.shapes.push(shape);
}

Paint.prototype.render = function() {

 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.element.width, this.element.height);

 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  try {
   this.shapes[i].makeSelection();
  }
  catch(err) {}
  try {
   if(this.shapes[i].lastClicked == true) {
    this.shapes[i].rect.makeCurvedRect();
   }
  }
  catch(err) {}
 }

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle='white';
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, (c.height*(25/500)));
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.fillStyle='#BC77BA';
 ctx.fillRect(0, (c.height*(450/500)), c.width, (c.height*(50/500)));
 ctx.stroke();

 ctx.font='bold '+(c.height*(10/500))+'px Noto Sans';
 ctx.fillStyle='#9F3A9B';
 ctx.textAlign='center';
 ctx.fillText('Test', (c.width*(365/750)), (c.height*(17/500)));
}

Paint.prototype.setHovered = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].hovered = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setClicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  this.shapes[i].clicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.setUnclicked = function(shape) {
 for (var i=0; i<this.shapes.length; i++) {
  if (shape.constructor.name==this.shapes[i].constructor.name) {
   this.shapes[i].clicked = false;
    if (shape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
    this.shapes[i].lastClicked = this.shapes[i] == shape;
    if (this.shapes[i].lastClicked == true) {
     this.shapes[i].rect.visible = true;
    } else {
     this.shapes[i].rect.visible = false;
    }
   }
  }
 }
 this.render();
}

Paint.prototype.select = function(x, y) {
 for (var i=this.shapes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (this.shapes[i].visible == true && this.shapes[i].hitTest(x, y)) {
   return this.shapes[i];
  }
 }
 return null
}

var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5];
var paint = new Paint(c);
var selection = [];
for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
 selection.push(new selectionForMenu(i+1, numbers[i], c.height*(25/500)+(c.height*((i*100)/500))));
}
for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
 var img = new curvedRect(i+1, (c.width*(112.5/750)), (c.height*(100/500)), (c.height*(175/500)), (c.height*(175/500)));
 paint.addShape(img)
 selection[i].rect = img;
}

for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
 paint.addShape(selection[i])
}

paint.render();

var clickedShape, clickIndex=0;
function mouseDown(event) {
 var x = (event.pageX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*c.width;
 var y = (event.pageY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*c.height;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (shape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
  if (clickIndex==0) {
   clickedShape=shape;
   clickIndex=1;
  } else if (clickIndex==1) {
   clickIndex=0;
  }
 }
 paint.setClicked(shape);
}

function mouseUp(event) {
 var x = (event.pageX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*c.width;
 var y = (event.pageY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*c.height;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);
 if (clickedShape instanceof selectionForMenu) {
  if (x>c.width*(400/750) && y>c.height*(25/500) && y<c.height*(450/500)) {
   paint.setUnclicked(shape);
  } else if (shape && !(shape instanceof selectionForMenu)) {
   paint.setUnclicked(shape);
  }
 }
}

function mouseMove(event) {
 var x = (event.pageX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left)*c.width;
 var y = (event.pageY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top)*c.height;
 var shape = paint.select(x, y);

 paint.setHovered(shape);
}

function paintCanvas() {
  c.width  = window.innerWidth;
  c.height = (2/3)*c.width;
  ctx=c.getContext('2d');

  rect = c.getBoundingClientRect();
 
  //paint = new Paint(c);
  selection = [];
  for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    selection.push(new selectionForMenu(i+1, numbers[i], c.height*(25/500)+(c.height*((i*100)/500))));
  }
  for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    var img = new curvedRect(i+1, (c.width*(112.5/750)), (c.height*(100/500)), (c.height*(175/500)), (c.height*(175/500)));
    paint.addShape(img)
    selection[i].rect = img;
  }

  for (var i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
    paint.addShape(selection[i])
  }
  paint.render();
}

paintCanvas();

window.addEventListener('resize', paintCanvas);
c.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);
c.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
c.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

```css
canvas {
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  background: #9F3A9B;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>uTalk Demo</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='wordpractice.css' media='screen'></style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='container'>
  <canvas id="game"></canvas>
 </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='scaleStack.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So this seems to be a step in the right direction, but how can I scale the image without redefining it and hence losing the selection? Also, do you know how I might set an initial selection?

Comment: More importantly, even after removing all of the `shapes` that aren't an `instance of curvedRect` there are _tracer_ shapes under the main `render` when the `window` is resized.